# Get variable by variable

Tags: javascript, variables

```
let varone = "vartwo";
let vartwo = "answer";
```

And I would like to get "answer". But I cannot do the following:

```
console.log(vartwo);
```

How can I get "answer", but not by including "vartwo" in my code?

Comment: You cannot form variable references dynamically, but you *can* do it for object properties. In my experience, there's almost always a better way of doing things, though it's hard to be specific because your posted code doesn't explain a lot about your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think one way to resolve it, is by using javascript objects, as shown:

```
    obj={
    varone:"vartwo",
    vartwo:"answer"
    };
   console.log(obj[varone]) //outputs "answer"
```